# Which of the new App Delegate methods for multitasking must I implement to retain the old behavior?

Tags: iphone, multitasking

For the moment I don't want to care about multitasking. My app has a very long development trip behind it, and now it has been engineered that way that when the user hits the home button, the app gets killed. When he comes back, the app appears like he left it.

If I wanted to get this same behavior back, which methods would I have to implement in the app delegate? I assume that I would have to treat the case where my app becomes a background app just like if the home button was pressed, i.e. if applicationWillTerminate was called. That would be the simplest way, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set a boolean flag in your `Info.plist` file called `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to `YES`. When you do so, when the user hits the home button, `-applicationWillTerminate` will get called, as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to `YES` in your Info.plist. Your customers will hate your app for not supporting fast app switching, though.

Answer (score 0):

Include the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key in your Info.plist. See [this](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW23) for more information.